# Idiomatic Qt way of storing localizable strings?

Tags: c++, qt, localization

Qt website recommends storing localizable strings right in the middle of the code like this:

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
```

However, how should I store strings that appear in the project multiple times? Putting them in a singleton works but `tr()` call means I have to initialize them separately:

```
struct MyLocalizableStrings
{
    QString mErrorMessageFileNotFound;
    QString mErrorMessageNoCanDoThis;

    MyLocalizableStrings() :
        mErrorMessageFileNotFound(QObject::tr("File not found.")),
        mErrorMessageNoCanDoThis(QObject::tr("Operation is not possible at the moment."))
        {}
};
```

It's clumsy and easy to mess up; I'd prefer to keep declaration and initialization together. Could of course keep a series of `const char*` in a dedicated namespace but then there's a risk of forgetting the `tr()` at the call site - this whole approach is seriously nonstandard.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Just use tr("foo") where ever you need it. Even though it looks like code duplication it's the best approach. Storing localizations in strings is not a good idea. Your MyLocalizableStrings prevents e.g. dynamic language change, unless you add a retranslate function... And here it is getting complex again. So, just use tr("foo") where ever you need it. Spelling mistakes can easily spotted through the linguist.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-qt-tr-noop-and-qt-translate-noop-in-c

Comment: @Lorenz It's worse than code duplication, it's data duplication. I would write "Operation not possible" in one function, "Operation not possible at the moment" in another one and in a year I wouldn't be able to remember if there's any semantic difference here. Even worse, it may be not me but a completely different person with no ability/time to inspect the code doing translation to a language where such things matter. Best practices exist for a reason: one does not duplicate hardcoded user-readable messages.

Comment: @Evgeny That's what I'm thinking about too right now: an `std::map` of mnemonics and strings. Still clumsy.

Comment: @sigil Why would you want to use a map? You're adding an unnecessary layer of indirection.

Comment: @sigil Right, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings that appear multiple times *and are meant to be the same* need to be in one or more dedicated classes - so you almost got it right. The class needs its translation context to make it easier for translators to understand that those are common messages. You should also leverage the member initialization in C++11 to DRY:

First, let's get a base class and necessary helpers established:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

template <typename Derived>
class LocalizableStringBase {
   Q_DISABLE_COPY(LocalizableStringBase)
protected:
   using S = QString;
   static LocalizableStringBase * m_instance;
   LocalizableStringBase() {
      Q_ASSERT(!m_instance);
      m_instance = this;
   }
   ~LocalizableStringBase() {
      m_instance = nullptr;
   }
public:
   static const Derived * instance() {
      return static_cast<const Derived*>(m_instance);
   }
   void reset() {
     auto self = static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
     self->~Derived();
     new (self) Derived();
   }
};

#define DEFINE_LOCALIZABLE_STRINGS(Derived) \
   template <> \
   LocalizableStringBase<Derived> * LocalizableStringBase<Derived>::m_instance = {}; \
   const Derived & Derived##$() { return *(Derived::instance()); }
```

Then, for each set of localizable strings you'd need:

```
// Interface

class MyLocalizableStrings : public LocalizableStringBase<MyLocalizableStrings> {
   Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS(MyLocalizableStrings)
public:
   S errorMessageFileNotFound = tr("File not found.");
   S errorMessageNoCanDoThis = tr("Operation is not possible at the moment.");
};

// Implementation

DEFINE_LOCALIZABLE_STRINGS(MyLocalizableStrings)
```

Usage:

```
#include <QDebug>

void test() {
   qDebug() << MyLocalizableStrings$().errorMessageFileNotFound;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   MyLocalizableStrings str1;
   test();
   // Change language here
   str1.reset();
   test();
}
```

This is fairly readable and there's no duplication of identifiers. It also avoids the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: Thank you for your traditionally competent and comprehensive answer! Maybe I'll use it to replace the inferior `std::map` approach I settled on yesterday mostly because of its simplicity.

Comment: There is still the issue, at least for me, that this approach does not support dynamic language change. Wouldn't a simple static class function be enough? `class TrStrings : public QObject {Q_OBJECT public: static QString errorMessage() {return tr("error");}};`

Comment: @Lorenz It does support dynamic language change. You have to re-create the `MyLocalizableStrings` object upon language change, and invoke `QWidget::update()` on top-level windows, with the assumption that all widgets are configured to get their text directly from the strings class.